# DataBinding C# ObservableCollection SerialPort to Combobox (SerialPort.getPortNames=>Method that return array of string)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, serial-port

I need to Bind a list of my Available ports in Computer to a Combobox in WPF. I am using ObservableCollection. I have done like

```js
public class MainWindowVM
    {
      public ObservableCollection<String[]> ListOfAvaliablePorts { get; set; }

        public MainWindowVM()
        {
            ListOfAvaliablePorts = new ObservableCollection<String[]>();
            ListOfAvaliablePorts.Add(SerialPort.GetPortNames());       
        }
    }
```

But the output on the combobox Output is 
[String[] Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukuhs.png)

My Xaml Code is

```html
     <!--#region Combobox-->
            <ComboBox
                Name="portsCombobox" Width="80" Margin="50,0,0,0" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfAvaliablePorts}">
            </ComboBox>
            <!--#endregion-->
```

Please help me to solve the problem so that i can get the output like
[COM1 COM2 COM6 COM7 COM5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fib7u.png)

Comment: then you need `IEnumerable<string>` not `IEnumerable<string[]>` obviously `string[]` is `IEnumerable<string>`... so why not `public string[] ListOfAvaliablePorts => ....` filling the dots is your homework **edit: why it has +1?**

Comment: .... `public string[] ListOfAvaliablePorts => SerialPort.GetPortNames();` obviously would be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initalize the ObservableCollection of string and give the list of ports.

```
public ObservableCollection<String> ListOfAvaliablePorts { get; set; }


 ListOfAvaliablePorts = new ObservableCollection<String>(SerialPort.GetPortNames());
```

Comment: using `string[].ToList<String>` is redundant ... using `string[].ToList()` when `IEnumerable<string>` is expected is also redundant

Comment: Corrected the ToList<String> to  toList().

Comment: there is no need to call ToList() at all

Comment: Yes no need to call ToList(), it shows the list of Comport without using ToList()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a string array, then it just **ObservableCollection** . And you also need to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** to raise the property change.

You can take a look as my solution as bellow:

```
public class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _ListOfAvaliablePorts;

    public ObservableCollection<string> ListOfAvaliablePorts
    {
        get
        {
            return _ListOfAvaliablePorts;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _ListOfAvaliablePorts)
            {
                _ListOfAvaliablePorts = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListOfAvaliablePorts));
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        var comPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        _ListOfAvaliablePorts = new ObservableCollection<string>(comPorts);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it shows the data as required. But When i removed the Com port it didn't update the list though. Anyway restarting program will do a work for me. Thank you for your help. Have a time